# How to stop and save during a 'Progressive Refine' render in progress?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, interface

When using the **Progressive Refine** render option, how do I actually stop a render prematurely and save it? I understand that is one of the benefits as I've read here and elsewhere, but I can't seem to find an answer or figure that aspect of it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop a render in process, be it progressive or not simply press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

You can also click the x next to the progress bar in the *Info header* to do the same thing.  [image]

To save the image, press <kbd>F3</kbd> with your mouse in the *UV/Image Editor* window with the *Render Result* or output from the compositor *Viewer Node* displayed.

Comment: Simple enough, I just couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out. Nice format with the screen too, thanks again.

Comment: @Chris no problem, glad to help. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted under the voting buttons if this resolved your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it up an up vote, but didn't know to also accept it. Thanks again!